# How to convert comma separated string values into a List<string> using asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

want to convert comma separated string values into a List

have tried

```
public List<string> GetColumnNamesByReportname(string Reportname)
{
    using (var Context = new MCPEntities())
    {
        var ColumnNames = Context.Reports.Where(c => c.ReportName == Reportname).Select(c => c.ColumnNames).ToList();
        return ColumnNames; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Nuget package: CSVHelper

Comment: Hi... Your code is fine! What problem are you having? What's the contents of ColumnNames that you split!

Comment: List<string> ReportColumnsList = DBFunctionOBj.GetColumnNamesByReportname(Reportname);
here getting comma values in ReportColumnsList . need to dispaly seperated values

Comment: @VenkataSeshu - That is returning a list of strings?! Not a comma seperated list!

Comment: yes ..  need to convert seperate values in listbox

Comment: @VenkataSeshu - OK... look I'll post you an answer... but your code was fine before you edited it and removed the split!

Comment: @VenkataSeshu - done!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      //Your original string
      string yourCommaDelimitedString = "TN,KA,KL";

      //Use the String.Split() method to break the string into an array containing all of your values and then
      //convert it to a List using the Enumerable.ToList() method
      List<string> yourValues = yourCommaDelimitedString.Split(',').ToList();

      //Add your values to the ViewData to be bound to a DropDown
      ViewData["Options"] = new SelectList(yourValues);

      return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Your code goes here
                string a="a,b,c,d";

              List<string> abc=a.Split(',').ToList();
                foreach(var item in abc){
                    Console.WriteLine(item);}
            }
```

Comment: any name space need to add for getting Split ()

Comment: you only need @using System;

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can use `a.Split(new char[]{ ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` *if* you want to get rid of the eventual empty strings in your list. For example `"aa,bb,,cc,dd"` would produce `["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]` instead of `["aa", "bb", "", "cc", "dd"]`.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say we have a class called "Report" that has a name and a list of column names in CSV form.

```
public class Report
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnNames { get; set; }
}
```

Then we have a class called "Context" that holds a list of reports.

```
public class ContextClass
{
    public List<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Then we initialize the Context class with a new report called "Report1" that has 3 columns and add it to the list

```
 var Context = new ContextClass();
 Context.Reports = new List<Report>();
 Context.Reports.Add(new Report()
 {
      ReportName = "Report1",
      ColumnNames = "Col1,Col2,Col3"
 });
```

Then in the context of your method, a "ReportName" is passed in called "Report1"

```
 var ReportName = "Report1";
```

We can then return the values as a list of string as per your original posted code"

```
 var ColumnNames = Context.Reports.Where(c => c.ReportName == ReportName).Select(c => c.ColumnNames.Split(',')).ToList();
 return ColumnNames
```

I've tested this locally and it works fine.

Thanks